# DS Photo Instant upload sync'ed my photos in 2 ways

Tags: sync, ios, synology

I have activated the Instant Upload feature on my iOS device. So, my iOS Photos are automatically upladed to a given folder on my Synology DiskStation.

My problem is that I need to make free space on my iOS device. **I want to delete some pictures** on it, so I did it. But, after a couple of hours ( or days I don't know exactly), the pictures I've deleted are restored!

I've searched on the parameters of Photo Station (server side), and also on DS Photo + app, but I found nothing.

Any idea?

*Config*: DS212j with DSM 4.0 and Photo Station 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't an option to only upload photos.  They call it "Instant Upload" but it should be called "Instant Sync".

Our work around is more manual than I'd like, but it works.

We created a new photo album called "MobileSync".  Each family phone that syncs to our drive has their own folder in this album.  Once the files are uploaded to Synology, we go through, categorize, and move to their permanent place.  By moving them out of the folder we've told Instant Upload to sync with, they don't get pulled back down into the device.